# Using angular.module().controller() with tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am create my controllers with the `module().controller()` syntax.

```
angular.module('App', []);

angular.module('App').controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.phones = [
        {
            "name": "Nexus S",
            "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."
        },
        {
            "name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
            "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
        },
        {
            "name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
            "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
        }
    ];
}]);
```

That works great. But now I want to test it with jasmine, and my test respond with

`ReferenceError: AppController is not defined`.

My test:

```
/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function () {

    describe('PhoneListCtrl', function () {

        it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function () {
            var scope = {},
                ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

            expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
        });
    });
});
```

If I change the controller to a classic function, the test works fine.

What do I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you should not create controller instances "by hand" but let AngularJS create instances using the `$controller` service. This is necessary since AngularJS DI system needs to have a chance to inject dependencies.

Your test should roughly look like:

```
 beforeEach(module('App'));

 it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    var ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: $rootScope});   
    expect($rootScope.phones.length).toBe(3);
 }));
```

Comment: After several tests, I found that out, that I must load the module before resolve the controller.

beforeEach(module('App'));

Comment: Why do all examples and your code use `var ctrl = ...`? That variable is never used, and if I understand it correctly, it is always `{}`.

Comment: where do the functions inject and and module come from? when i console.log(typeof module) i get undefined when i run my test.

Answer (score -1):

For people who are looking to t instantiate a new scope and use it:

```
    var ctrl = $scope.$new();
$controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: ctrl});   
    expect(ctrl.phones.length).toBe(3);
```